# Monte Carlo Simulations in Python

Tags: simulations

I wrote a few lines of code below in python.
My intentions are to generate 1000 different values   of 'φ' and 'Λ' and in each case it should choose a new value of 'a' from a random range (0,1).

Then convert the values   "φ" and "Λ" from cylindrical coordinates to cartesian coordinates and show the plot in the graph.

How do I generate different values   of "φ" and "Λ" in this case? And I tried to convert to Cartesian but it rather shows an empty plot.
Please what do I need to do at this point in order to arrive at my results.

I sincerely appreciate your past contributions and I look forward to your help, thanks.

```
# import the necessary libraries
import math
import random
from math import pi

N = 1000

for num in range(N):
    a = random.uniform(0,1)
# I am using these symbols for: λ - lambda null, Λ - mean free path, φ = angle
λ = -1
φ = 2*pi*a 
Λ = λ*math.log(a) 

x = Λ*math.cos(φ) 
y = Λ*math.sin(φ)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Try printing `x` and `y`, and not just plotting them. You may find the problem is with `matplotlib.pyplot`, not the rest.

Comment: little suggestion: do not use special characters in scripting or coding. Use "phi" instead of "$\phi$"

Comment: I've tried your code. `x` and `y` are each only one number, and that's not what you want. If you replace each `math` and `random` function with its `numpy` counterpart, or make lists and append to them in the `for` loop, it'll work.

Comment: Thank you very much @J.G for your valuable inputs. I have printed x and y as you rightly suggested, I got a single values for x and y. My intention is to generate 1000 different values of 'phi' and 'lambda' and to plot them. Please how may I do that?

Comment: The problem with your for loop is that only the line `a = random.uniform(0,1)` is inside it. What comes after it must be indented to match the columns of `a`.  Effectively you see the last value of `a` in your code so far. I think only `plt.show()` can stay on the left where it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure your transformation is correct? You are using the single random variable $a$ to generate points $\phi,\,\lambda$, which means that you are tracing a path along a [log-polar coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-polar_coordinates) (not 2D cylindrical, as you are using $\log(a)$ instead of $\sqrt{a}$). For instance, running JG's code (but using `scatter()` instead of `plot()`) I get,

[image]

Which seems wrong to me, as you are doing a transformation $\mathbb{R}^1\to\mathbb{R}^2$. I would think you need a transformation of $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ in order to plot a randomly/uniformly distributed series of points on the domain. This would be done by using *two* arrays of random values,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 1000
a = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=N)
b = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=N)
lam = -np.log(a)
phi = np.arccos(b)
plt.scatter(lam * np.cos(phi), lam * np.sin(phi))
plt.plot()
```

which gives a plot more like,

[image]

Note that using $\phi=\cos^{-1}(x)$ for $x\in\operatorname{Uniform}(-1,1)$ is for removing biases from sampling $\operatorname{Uniform}(0,\,2\pi)$ (cf. [this site](https://blog.thomaspoulet.fr/uniform-sampling-on-unit-hemisphere/), among others for *sampling the hemisphere*).

Comment: Thank you very much @Kyle Kanos for your useful inputs. They are greatly appreciated. Some other concerns are, (a) the scattering points only concentrates between (0 and pi) that is from 0 to 180 degrees. How do I make the scattering symmetrical such that the points are all scattered in all directions covering between (0 to 2Pi)? (b) How do I also show the distances between one point to another in a visible chat? Thank you and everyone for your valuable contributions. I truly appreciate them all.

Comment: For (a), I would look at the site I linked at the bottom of the answer as it indicates how one needs to think about such transformations. For (b), I am not sure what you are asking. Do you mean how to pick two points and connect them via a straight line in the chart? Or simply how to calculate the distances and display them?

Comment: Thank you again for your continued help. I have checked this site https://blog.thomaspoulet.fr/uniform-sampling-on-unit-hemisphere/ and other references but I have not been able to arrive at the desired answer yet. As for, the (b) part, I understand how to do it now. Thank you very much for every help.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on my comments while also taking advice from @basics, you want something like

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.sort(np.random.uniform(size=1000))
Lambda, phi = -np.log(a), 2*np.pi*a 
plt.plot(Lambda*np.cos(phi), Lambda*np.sin(phi))
plt.show()
```

A `numpy`-free solution would be something like

```
from matplotlib import pylot as plt
import math, random

a = sorted(random.random() for _ in range(1000))
Lambda, phi = [-math.log(x) for x in a], [2*math.pi*x for x in a] 
plt.plot(*zip(*((L*math.cos(p), L*math.sin(p)) for L, p in zip(Lambda, phi))))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Numpy version: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxFjUEOwjAMBO-R8gcfkwqqwr0_4BMupTRSHFtJKlRej0OROHk9u6tdMhMQVolcY5ggkHCuIHsDgAUkVmt-NG0ke4NJrLEGYVTVF7Wc3oxpZuq3FBbO5Ep4P8bLMAzeW3NDmmY8gaxBS2dNR3469Ce4dvpI6BCs0a2-7boj3pw7F6clDf5ZCenL_NEoK7-c_wDWzUHn&lang=python